# How to protect the source code?

Tags: php, zend-framework, architecture, software-design

I am developing a system in `Zend Framework` for a company and once its finished I want to sell this system to other companies as well.

The problem here is that the first company whom I am going to sell the system has its own IT department so I suspect they will make some tweaks in the system which I developed and start selling it to other companies.

My question here is that how can I make this system in such manner that it take a lot of time and effort to analyze and is hard to understand?

I all ready know about the confusing directory structure...but looking for other alternatives..

And also according to contract I have to give them raw source code.

Comment: If you have to give "raw" code, and they have an IT department, then anything you give them that's still "raw" is going to be quite easy to read.

Comment: @hexacyanide I don't mind them reading the code but I want to make this hard. Few years back I had analyzed a commercial system and the directory structure, coding, flow was so hard that it took months to understand the whole system. I just want to make their life harder...

Comment: any reason to make source code hard to read? i always love code to be as simple as possible.

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi its mentioned in the question.

Comment: I read about it, but i am not agree here, either sell it as a product to that company with a proper license terms or be ready to share your source code.Moreover i do not see any reason to make it more complex just to get sometime, and also if i go with legal terms company is paying you what they have asked to develop.

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi "i do not see any reason to make it more complex" so in your understanding making your code hard to reversed engineered is not a good idea? and it should be kept "simple as possible" so any new kid on the block can copy it..

Comment: yes,and if you want to make it protected just create a product and release it with a proper license.I am not sure about your approach as if someone want to recompile your code , there is no way to stop it and instead of tweaking code, i would love to spend that time to either improve my application or add more features to it.

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi My question is about not making the raw code impossible to reverse engineered. I all ready know its not possible. Also licences don't protect me against tweaks, it they use and tweak my code there is no way to prove that. My question here is how to make it hard, the reason behind is simple, you can either pay few hundred buying a new copy or you can waste time ("This is what I want to do") of your IT team and make even more loss..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as if you have opposing ideas. If you are worried about them taking your code, then you shouldn't sell it to them. There is no way to have unencrypted source code, and keep it a secret at the same time. But, to answer your question, I recommend you take a look at the javascript that google uses on gmail, or any of their other web apps, you'll notice that all of their variable names have been not only minified, but renamed to things like "var a, b, t;", instead of variable names like "var alpha, beta, theta;". So you could "disguise" your code in this way to make it less readable, but that isn't really doing much, since any skilled and determined developer could figure it out.

Comment: Good solution, I can use this with complex directory structure...Thanks...

Comment: i'm not capitalist, it's not for monney, its for prevent cheat in game ;) I already oblivious my var's names, but I discover just yet the "Seal" methode, and I search how use it to forbidden modify the game var